# Low-pass filter with a load

Tags: capacitor, voltage-divider, low-pass

how can be the voltage of a low-pass filter be mathematically described when a load is connected? Is it possible to ignore the effect of the load on its voltage as something like this circuit can be connected to a common base circuit. I assume the capacitor acts like a stabilizer for the voltage divider.

[image]

Comment: Your circuit doesn't make much sense. You need to show the input voltage node and the output voltage node. You also need to put resistor designators on it if you want a mathematical formula. Your grounding nodes are ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If the RC filter has R as load, it's just a resistive divider with a cap.

The resistors and supply can be replaced with Thevenin equivalent circuit with lower supply of divider output and single resistor matching the impedance of the divider output.

Answer (score 0):

it is usual to arrange things so that the load is much higher than the output impedance of the filter. Often something like an op amp voltage follower will be used, which has such a high input impedance (many megohms) that its effect can be neglected.

(In this case though, as we are already using an op amp stage, we might go a step further by designing a simple active filter. It depends on what we are trying to achieve.)

(As a friendly comment, take more care over your schematic. Arrange components logically, label them, and use consistent and clear symbols for ground and other nodes. This will benefit you and also encourage others to respond to your questions in a helpful way.)